# On Error Resume Next to ignore Error 440 when attempting to create an existing folder

Tags: vba, error-handling, outlook

**Step 1:**
I want to make a folder, and if it fails (it may already exist), I want to ignore and move on.

```vb
Sub MakeFolder()

'declare variables
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace

'set up folder objects    
Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set NS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objOwner = NS.CreateRecipient("email@host.com")
objOwner.Resolve
Set outlookInbox = NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)

'make a folder, maybe
Dim newFolder 
On Error Resume Next
Set newFolder = outlookInbox.Folders.Add("myNewFolder")
On Error GoTo -1
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I get an error:
[image]

If the folder doesn't exist, it creates it.

**Step2:**
I have a list of folders (about 60) that may change over time. Because of this, I'd like to run a script checking for new folders and then create them.

```vb
For Each fol In folders
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newFolder = outlookInbox.Folders.Add(fol)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo -1
    Else:
        Debug.Print fol & " created "
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next ID
```

Same here, the `outlookInbox.Folders.Add()` throws errors regardless of the return next, if it can't create that folder.

Comment: In the IDE, go to Tools>Options>General and make sure that under the Error Trapping block you don't have it set to "Break on All Errors".

Comment: You are writing Resume Next or GoTo 0 but I don’t see any Next or 0....

Comment: @IRENEG `On Error Resume Next` doesn't require to be within a `For...Next` loop. It's the normal way of telling VBA to just swallow any errors that occur. Likewise, `GoTo 0` is the normal way of telling VBA to resume normal error-handling and does not require a label 0.

Comment: @ David Zemens
that did the trick. i really feel defeated by this "IDE"
I now remember setting this option as to gain the "debug" button in case of an error....

Comment: hahah yeah I've been there before, it's pretty rare that you should need to toggle that from anything other than "Break on unhandled errors". Basically, you don't (usually) want your code to throw the Debug dialog box if the error is trapped by an `On Error...` statement (you could add a MsgBox call or a breakpoint instead, if you need to debug/examine some thing, just be sure to remove before distributing to others..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Now that you fixed your IDE, you could use the following code*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.Folder
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.Folder

    '// SubFolder Name
    Dim FolderName As String
    FolderName = "myNewFolder"

    '// Check if folder exist else create one
    If FolderExists(Inbox, FolderName) = True Then
        Debug.Print "Folder Exists"
        Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(FolderName)
    Else
        Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders.Add(FolderName)
    End If

End Sub


'//  Function - Check folder Exist
Private Function FolderExists(Inbox As Folder, FolderName As String)
    Dim Sub_Folder As MAPIFolder

    On Error GoTo Exit_Err
    Set Sub_Folder = Inbox.Folders(FolderName)

    FolderExists = True
        Exit Function

Exit_Err:
    FolderExists = False

End Function
```

Comment: If the IDE is configured to "Break on all errors" (as in the OP's case) this will not avoid the error. It is nice to compartmentalize your code & error handling as you've done here, but this doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for this version of the "check folder & in case create it". i've seen various others, but this one looks nice.

Comment: I had to specify the function as boolean, otherwise it works like a charm! finally a nice solution (at the standards of VBA).